# How do you reset the position of an Animation in Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to get a handle on Animations. The problem that I'm having is that my Animation plays once but does not repeat.

**What I want to do:** I want the image to slide up, and then off the screen. Then appear at the bottom of the screen and again slide up and off.

**What actually happens:** The Image slides "up" the screen, disappears off of the screen and that's it. It doesn't reset back to its original location, and it doesn't repeat.

**My question is:** How can I reset the position of the image so that it continues in a never-ending cycle (until the "Stop Animation" button is clicked)?

**The animated object is the Image that's setup in .kv language it's directly under MyScreen**

If you want to see how the animation plays just change the name of the image "binary_rain.png" in kv lang to w/e you have :)

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FallOutTransition
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.animation import Animation

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.example_func, 20.0)    
    self._test_bool = False

    self.water = Animation(pos=(0, 800)) # It's setup in __init__ ; here
    self.water &= Animation(size=(800, 800), duration=2, t='in_back') # and then here



    def example_func(self, dt):
        if self._test_bool == True:
            self.ids.text_input_test_id.foreground_color = 255,0,0,1
            self.ids.text_input_test_id.text = "The color has been changed"
            self._test_bool = False 
        elif self._test_bool != True:
            self.ids.text_input_test_id.foreground_color = 0, 255, 0, 1
            self.ids.text_input_test_id.text = "The color has changed"       
            self._test_bool = True    

    def test_func(self):
        if self._test_bool == True:
            self.ids.text_input_2.foreground_color = 255,0,0,1
            self.ids.text_input_2.text = "The color has been changed"
            self._test_bool = False 
        elif self._test_bool != True:
            self.ids.text_input_2.foreground_color = 0, 255, 0, 1
            self.ids.text_input_2.text = "The color has changed"       
            self._test_bool = True    


    def test_func_two(self):
        if self._test_bool == True:
            self.ids.text_input_3.foreground_color = 255,0,0,1
            self.ids.text_input_3.text = "The color has been changed"
            self._test_bool = False 
        elif self._test_bool != True:
            self.ids.text_input_3.foreground_color = 0, 255, 0, 1
            self.ids.text_input_3.text = "The color has changed"       
            self._test_bool = True

    def start_my_animation(self): # this is what starts the animation
        self.water.repeat = True
        self.water.start(self.ids.animated_bacground)

    def stop_my_animation(self): # this is what should end the animation
        self.water.stop(self.ids.animated_bacground)

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass 




root_widget = Builder.load_string('''

#:import FallOutTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FallOutTransition
#:import Config kivy.config
#:import Window kivy.core.window
#:import Clock kivy.clock
#:import ActionBar kivy.uix.actionbar
#:import Animation kivy.animation.Animation
MyScreenManager:
    transition: FallOutTransition()
    MyScreen:

<MyScreen>:
    name: 'example_screen'
    Image:
        id: animated_bacground
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        source: 'binary_rain.png'

    TextInput:
        id: text_input_test_id   
        size_hint: .3, .05
        pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .85}
        text: 'Hello'
        font: '12sp'
    TextInput: 
        id: text_input_2
        size_hint: .3, .05
        pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .70}
        text: 'Hello'
        font: '12sp'
    TextInput:
        id: text_input_3
        size_hint: .3, .05
        pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .65}
        text: 'Button 3'


    Button:
        id: test_button_id
        size_hint: .3, .05
        pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': .5}
        text: 'Click me'
        on_press: root.test_func()


    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Menu'
                with_previous: False
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                text: 'click me'
                on_press: root.test_func_two()                
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Start Animation'
                on_press: root.start_my_animation()
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Stop Animation'
                on_press: root.stop_my_animation()
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Button 2'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Button 3'
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'Group1'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Button 5'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn6'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn7'     

''')
Factory.unregister('ActionPrevious')
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Example App'
        return root_widget



TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation is setting the size, not the pos...
also you are doing both animations in the same time using **&=**, you need **+=**

```
self.water = Animation(pos=(0, 800))
# notice the changes * pos * and * += *
self.water += Animation(pos=(800, 800), duration=2, t='in_back') # and then here
```

Comment: This makes sense, can't believe I missed that, thanks!